# Updating MySQL Table with AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to send a value for an item in a MySQL table and increment its "availability" column by one.

A press of a button executes the following onclick function:

```
function updateStuff() {

// Data validation for string variable val 
// coordinating to one of the items in the SQL table

var xmlHttp = false;

if(window.ActiveXObject){  
    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
else{
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}

if(!xmlHttp)
    alert("Error : Cannot create xmlHttp object");
else{
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 0 || xmlHttp.readyState == 4){
        xmlHttp.open("GET","update.php?val=" + val, true);
        xmlHttp.send(); 
    }
    else{
      setTimeout(updateStuff,1000);
      }
}
```

}

update.php looks like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';

echo '<response>';
$item = $_GET['val'];
echo 'You selected ' . $item;

$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$datab = "checkout";

// Connect to database
$db = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $datab);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo "Could not connect to database: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$results = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE item = " . $item);
$available = $results['available'] + 1;
$result = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE inventory SET available = " . $available . " WHERE item = " + $item);

// Close connection 
mysqli_close($db);

echo '</response>';

?>
```

I think this is generally correct, unfortunately I'm not getting a table update when I execute the code. I am 100% confident in the validation for the variable `val`, and fairly confident with `updateStuff()`, but I'm less sure if I'm handling the server-side stuff corecctly with putting `$_GET` inside of `response` tags.

EDIT: I have made the syntax correction given by asparatu, but the problem persists.

Comment: I think there is a typo error. please correct the line to
$result = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE inventory SET available = available + 1 WHERE item = ".$item);

Comment: So you're saying to get `$oldValue = /* SQL for the old value*/`, then run `mysqli_query` using that variable name instead of "available"? How would that help exactly? Thanks for the input.

EDIT: I see where the `Set available = available + 1` might be a problem - I will use a variable instead and see if that helps

Comment: hey btw be careful there. you are concatenating your GET input directly into your sql through the `$item` variable. I believe this leads to sql injection vulnerability. you should definitely check that out.

Comment: Do you know what the right way to do this would be then? I'm just trying to get any kind of a sign that `update.php` is receiving what it should from `updateStuff()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this to update query:

```
$result = "UPDATE inventory SET available = "' .$available. '" WHERE item = "' .$item. '"";    
if (mysqli_query($db, $result)) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($db);
}
```

Comment: No change unfortunately

Comment: print query and see what is happening?

Comment: Can you give me the function for this? I've been looking for something like that to do but I haven't found it yet. Would I print this out in an alert or something similar?

Comment: I cannot get any sort of an echo to output since I have no server response set up in `buttonHandler`, mainly because I'm not trying to update an interface or anything only change the variables, so I'm lost on how to output something for me to use to debug.

Comment: The val variable corresponds to the value of a dropdown menu of all of the items in the table - it is a check in/check out system. So it would be "camera_one" or "camera_three", etc. which all match one of the values in the 'items' column in the table

Comment: can't you echo the query?

Comment: The `echo You selected ' . $item;` line at the top of `update.php` does nothing currently - when I click the "submit" button from my index page nothing at all happens. I think to do that I would have to update a `<div>` field, which would mean I would need a server response, which is not set up.

Comment: Yes I did, and thank you very much for it, that's exactly what I want to get working. However I'm still not getting anything. Would providing my index page (which just calls buttonHandler.js) be any help? I think my problems are bigger than MySQL, I think it's ajax not working.

Comment: there should some error printing, if not updating the table row

Comment: Right - that's why I posted the question in the first place because I can't get any feedback from it! I almost think the entire file isn't being called properly from `updateStuff()`

Answer (score 1):

The update query is wrong.

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE inventory SET available = available + 1 WHERE item = " + $item);
```

Where are you getting the current number for available?

you need a select statement that queries the current item and get current available amount then you can add one to it.

```
$results = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE item = " . $item);
$available = $results['available'] + 1;

$result = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE inventory SET available = " . $available . " WHERE item = " . $item);
```

That should work..

Comment: Good catch - I have made the edit. Unfortunately the table is still not updating its 'available' column for the item.

Comment: I made this mistake to you have to concatenate the string with a period and not a plus symbol.

Comment: Same thing :\ Is there a way to see the value of `item` with an alert to narrow it down to a MySQL problem? I haven't had any luck getting one to pop up.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Sorry, I normally do not post anything answers to question, but i do ask a lot question sometimes. Thank you..